# Is there a verb form of the word "agenda", as in, to create a political agenda for or against something?

Tags: single-word-requests

It doesn't have to contain the root word, but I would like at least a synonym.

Comment: I hear what @Scott hears, that the OP is asking about activism, not the open agendas of meetings. More like angling, jockeying, politicizing, planning behind the scenes, and conniving for hidden agendas.

Answer (score 1):

You might hear **set an agenda**.

> **set** *verb* (establish)
>
> to establish or decide something
>
> e.g. *The committee has set new limits on spending.*

*Source: [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/set)*

Comment: +1. Depending on context it may be better to say **set the agenda**. I think when not actually talking about meetings but "political will" that would be more common.